# Efficiently sum all elements of vector that add upp to no more than a specified limit

Tags: r

Need to apply code that has the following effect on a huge data set:

```r
sum_to_limit <- function(x, limit) {
    ret <- 0
    if (length(na.omit(x)) > 0) {
        for (i in seq_along(x)) {
            if (ret + x[i] <= limit) ret <- ret + x[i]
        }
    }
    return(ret)
}
```

In other words, I need to sum up all the elements of the supplied vector that add up to  no more than `limit`. So for example `sum_to_limit(c(10,10,10,10,5), 17) = 15`. Have so far failed to come up with anything faster than above, which is not really cutting it on my data. Feels like it should be possible to create a vectorized version...

Comment: What's the desired result from `sum_to_limit(c(10,10,7,6,5), 17)`?  Can we guarantee that the input vector is sorted?

Comment: `sum_to_limit(c(10,10,7,6,5), 17) = 17`. So order matters but it does not have to be sorted.

Comment: `sum_to_limit(c(1,rep(5, 10), 1), 3) = 2`

Comment: You could add a `break`, if `ret == limit`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an optimization problem. Might only be worth if you have longer vectors rather than multiple small ones:

```
library(lpSolve)
sum_to_limit <- function(x, limit) {
  
  sol <- lp ("max", 
      objective.in = rep(1, length(x)),
      const.mat = matrix(x, nrow=1),
      const.dir = "<=", 
      const.rhs = limit,
      all.bin = T)
  
  stopifnot(sol$status==0) # no solution
  
  return(x[sol$solution==1])
}



print(sum_to_limit(c(10,10,10,10,5), 17))
```

I found it more interesting to return the selected entries rather than the sum.

Comment: Ah thats a direction i didn't even think about going, thanks! In my case its millions of vectors but most have less than 10 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can `sort` the vector and add them upto they are less than the `limit`.

```
sum_to_limit <- function(x, limit) {
  x <- sort(x)
  sum(x[cumsum(x) <= limit])
}

sum_to_limit(c(10,10,10,10,5), 17) 
#[1] 15

sum_to_limit(c(10,10,10,10,5), 35) 
#[1] 35
```

Comment: Tried this at first but it does not work. For example `sum_to_limit(sum_to_limit(c(15,1,3), 17) = 4` but it should be 16.